# How to get the message before the last message in discord jda (lists)

Tags: java, discord

i am trying to get the message before the last message in discord jda.

I've tried this but it gives me an IndexOutOfBounds exception.

```
event.getChannel().getHistory().getRetrievedHistory().get(1)
```

Could you please explain to me why it's doing this and point me in the right direction so i can finish my project? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageHistory.html#getRetrievedHistory()) of `getRetrievedHistory()`:

> The List of Messages, sorted starting from newest to oldest, of all message that have already been retrieved from Discord with this MessageHistory object using the `retrievePast(int)`, `retrieveFuture(int)`, and `MessageChannel.getHistoryAround(String, int)` methods.
>
> This will be empty if it was just created using MessageChannel.getHistory() or similar methods. ***You first have to retrieve messages.***

So you have to use `retrievePast(2)` to get the second most recent message:

```java
channel.getHistory().retrievePast(2)
       .map(messages -> messages.get(1)) // this assumes that the channel has at least 2 messages
       .queue(message -> { // success callback
           System.out.println("The second most recent message is: " + message.getContentDisplay();
       });
```

Keep in mind that queue is **asynchronous**. This means code like this cannot work:

```java
MessageHistory history = channel.getHistory();
history.retrievePast(2).queue(); // <-- schedules the request, its not done when it returns
List<Message> message = history.getRetrievedHistory(); // <-- this is still empty
```